# Download a file on android from Chrome HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome

I have a HTTPS website where I have a download file using headers so I try to download it from an android tablet using Chrome and the test file has simply this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.KML"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Close');
header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('test.KML'));

echo var_dump(headers_list());
```

But from Chrome download starts but gives out "noname" filename so download doesn't really complete... If I do same test with Firefox always on Android then the download completes correctly.
So I tried to get same file from another site non-HTTPS using Chrome and the download went OK. So I decided to debug the download from Chrome using chrome://net-export and I obtained this result you can see on:

http://nunzioluigi.com/chrome-net-export-log.json

Looking at this result, do you expect something that could be related to a Chrome bug or even to a wrong HTTPS setting of the server which disallow to pass correctly through Chrome HTTPS the filename?....

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

At the end, after some further investigations I found the solution to the issue. 
I had to create certificates and to make connection secure so download file from Chrome goes ok with correct filenam. Lemme guess maybe with unsecure web connection just limit some functionalities from Chrome.

Hope this would solve same issue from someone else in my same situation!
Cheers 
Luigi